# Is there a VHDL (or Quartus2-specific) compiler directive for disregarding certain lines of code for synthesis?

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

Is there a VHDL (or Quartus2-specific) compiler directive for disregarding certain lines of code for synthesis?

I want to have certain signals going out for my simulation, but Quartus2 throws errors about insufficient numbers of IC pins, and besides it would be more correct to not have them in the synthesized design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [translate_on and translate_off](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_file_dir_translate.htm) compiler directives. Generally they are compiler specific and not a part of VHDL standard, but similar directives present in all major compilers. See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664368/how-does-synthesis-translate-off-work).

Comment: That's what I wanted, thanks! I guess if I wanted to be tool-independent, I could add all the flavours one after another. Since they are just comments to alien compilers, that should be ok. Assuming the other tools use the same basic syntax of line comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, which is to use the IF GENERATE VHDL construct

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/generate.html

As far as I know, the flag used for the IF GENERATE must be updated manually to differentiate between modes. The IF GENERATE can also be used for a crude version management on a single file.

Comment: How can it distinguish between simulation and synthesis?

Comment: Defining a variable that is true for simulation and false for synthesis. You would have to update the flag to true for simulation, manually.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned..

Comment: OK I included that on the answer

Comment: It wouldn't work for declaring ports in the entity, would it?

Comment: @Jacob You mean instantiating? Instantiating can be done inside of `generate` block.

Comment: I mean declaring ports in the top-level entity.

Comment: my_debug_port : out std_logic;

Comment: No, I don't think it can be used in the entity declaration area.